# Is There A Way to manage a Custom generated ID with IdentifierGenerator from Hibernate to serve more than one Entity with different prefix?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, entity, identifier

I have a custom ID generator that generates an UUID string with a prefix for my entities ID, but since I'm using different prefix for each entity I'm having to create one ID generation class for each Entity, is there a way to only use one class for this?

My ID generation class is this:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SharedSessionContractImplementor;
import org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerator;

public class ProductIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator{
    
    public static final String generatorName = "produtcIdGenerator";

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor arg0, Object arg1) throws 
HibernateException {
        
        String prefix = "PROD";
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);

        return prefix + uuid;
    }
}
```

My Entities looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = ProductIdGenerator.generatorName)
    @GenericGenerator(name = ProductIdGenerator.generatorName, strategy = "net.ddns.mrq.util.ProductIdGenerator")
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private String id;

    private String name;
    .
    .
    .
```

I have 8 entities and I had to create 8 classes like this for each of one them with different prefix.

1. Is there a way to make this more dynamic and less "time consuming"?
2. Is there a way to only change the prefix for each class without creating multiple id generation classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of ways to solve this (which is basically the need for a custom `IdentifierGenerator` to be parameterized).

One idea involves each entity implementing an interface that can return the appropriate ID prefix for that entity type. Since the target entity is passed to the generator's `generate()` method, the generator could cast it to that interface and ask it for the prefix to use.

Another solution takes advantage of the fact that `IdentifierGenerator`s can implement the `org.hibernate.id.Configurable` interface to have configuration "injected" into them, and the `@GenericGenerator` annotation supports setting those as `@Parameter`s in the annotation. That way, each usage of `@GenericGenerator` can dictate what prefix it wants the custom generator to use. It would look something like this (*note*, this is untested code):

```java
public class ProductIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator, org.hibernate.id.Configurable {

    public static final String GENERATOR_NAME = "produtcIdGenerator";
    public static final String PREFIX_PARAM = "prefix";

    private String prefix = "";

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params, ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {
        this.prefix = params.getProperty(PREFIX_PARAM, "");
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session, Object entityObject) throws HibernateException {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);

        return prefix + uuid;
    }
}
```

References to it would look like this:

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = ProductIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME)
    @GenericGenerator(
                    name = ProductIdGenerator.GENERATOR_NAME,
                    strategy = "net.ddns.mrq.util.ProductIdGenerator",
                    parameters = {@Parameter(name = ProductIdGenerator.PREFIX_PARAM, value = "foo")})
    private String id;
```

Personally, I find the second idea a little cleaner, but there's nothing wrong with the first that I can see. It's a matter of style.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I as looking for, the parameter think. And it seems that you don't need to implements the Configurable interface, the interface IdentifierGenerator already extends the Configurable interface. Thanks a lot

Comment: @ThiagoMarquet that's a recent change in the latest versions (6.x I think). For Hibernate 5.x, you need to implement `Configurable` like I show.

Comment: ***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.gemeja.usermanagementsystem.util.CustomUUIDGenerator required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.

Comment: @Zenonymous that sounds like a different question. Definitely not caused by the code posted here, but rather your own code maybe derived from this idea.

Comment: @E-Riz Yeah I've noticed that now. I did some digging and I finally make it work.